# Local image search against a source image?

Tags: images, search, desktop-search

I came across this: [Free visual similarity image for a local hard drive search?](https://superuser.com/questions/311633/is-there-a-free-visual-similarity-image-local-hard-drive-search). However, it doesn't answer the question and the solutions don't work.

Basically, I have a directory structure of images and I have to find all images, of varying sizes, etc, that contain this source image. In the end, we need a list of all images that contain this source image.

Is something available for use on a local hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Duplifinder](http://www.codeplex.com/DupliFinder) looks like it does what you need. Just select the root folder as the one you want to search, and search all subfolders. It will give you a percentage as to how related they are, handles different formats, resolutions, etc.

You might also want to try [SimilarImages](http://celebnamer.celebworld.ws/similarimages/) and  [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php). That last one might be the best of the lot.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it out and it didn't work. It found no duplicate images.

Comment: Did it find any files at all?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Are there any for linux?

Comment: Duplifinder works on linux.

Comment: The copy I downloaded from your link is a Windows executable. I meant natively.

Comment: The source code is available (see [here](http://duplifinder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)), just compile it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo.html. It locates same or similar images on your hard drive and it's free.